# Chart.js updating multiple charts

Tags: javascript, html, chart.js

I am using this function to update my a certain dataset of my chart but it doesn't seem to work and I don't understand why
Function:

```
`function addData(chart, label, data, i) {
    chart.data.labels.push(label);
    chart.data.datasets[i].data.push(data);
    chart.update();
   }`
```

When I run the following code each chart should update individually but they are all the same

```
`birdCount = document.getElementsByClassName("bird").length
        addData(chart, [Generation], [birdCount], 0)
        var birdCountST = document.getElementsByClassName("bird11").length + document.getElementsByClassName("bird12").length
        console.log(birdCountST,'shortthickguys')
        addData(chart, [Generation], [birdCountST], 1)
        var birdCountST = document.getElementsByClassName("bird11").length + document.getElementsByClassName("bird12").length
        addData(chart, [Generation], [birdCountST], 2)`
```

Comment: I think you are trying to push an array in an array and not the elements of the array

Comment: anyway I think it's better to add all new items and invoke once the chart.update

Comment: @user2057925 Thanks for your reply, how would I do this exactly?

Comment: function addData(chart, label, data, i) {
    chart.data.labels.push(...label);
    chart.data.datasets[i].data.push(...data);
    chart.update(); // <--- this could be moved after datasets changes
   }

Answer (score 0):

I am very stupid for not noticing but I didn't change the variable when I copied it
It should be like this: :facepalm:

```
`birdCount = document.getElementsByClassName("bird").length
    addData(chart, [Generation], [birdCount], 0)
    var birdCountST = document.getElementsByClassName("bird11").length + document.getElementsByClassName("bird12").length
    console.log(birdCountST,'shortthickguys')
    addData(chart, [Generation], [birdCountST], 1)
    var birdCountLT = document.getElementsByClassName("bird21").length + document.getElementsByClassName("bird22").length
    addData(chart, [Generation], [birdCountLT], 2)`
```

Comment: Please mind the vocabulary. Also try to add more supporting information.